# how to eliminate infinte loop in python

Tags: python, infinite-loop, turtle-graphics

I am trying to learn python and so far it has gone well. However i keep getting an infinite loop error after a while of my code running. The code given below is that of a star with 7 angles.

```
import turtle
n = 7
def drawStar(t, sz, s):


    """Get turtle t to draw a star of sz sides, s size"""

    for i in range(sz):

        t.right(180)       
        t.forward(s)
        t.right(180/n)


wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("lightgreen")

alex = turtle.Turtle()
alex.color("hotpink")

#
n = 7
for i in range(15):
    alex.up()    
    alex.forward(30)
    alex.right(144)
    alex.down() 
    print(n) 

    drawStar(alex,n,30)


wn.exitonclick()
```

Comment: always put FULL error message in QUESTION - we can't read in your mind and don't expect that we will run code to see this error message.

Comment: this code works for me without error. it draws 15 stars (`range(15)`) and stops. I don't see problem in this part of code. Maybe you have problem in different code.

Comment: This is not an infinite loop.

Comment: This is not an infinite loop for me either. The code draws five 7-pointed stars, then draws them again over the previous ones, then draws them again. The program then waits for a mouse click. Watching the stars being redrawn takes time and looks like an infinite loop, but it is not one. Change the range(15) to range(5) for better results.

Comment: Sorry for not including the full error message @furas. Thank you all so much. Now i think it is my program that might be causing the problem.

Comment: your problem is that it draws 15 stars - because you use `range(15)` - and it looks like it loops (but it ends after 15 stars - you have to wait). Use `range(5)` and it will draw less starts and it will ends faster.

Answer (score 0):

Folks have pointed out that your use of `range(15)` instead of `range(5)` redraws the stars three times making your program take longer.  (Sufficiently that you mistook it for an infinite loop.)

There are additional ways to improve the performance of the program.  The easy bandaid is to add `alex.speed("fastest")` which will cause the turtle to race through the drawing and end sooner.

However, if we instead do `alex.speed("slowest")` we'll see the other problem with the program: the turtle spends too much time turning one way and turning back the other.  At times it turns the long way around a circle instead of the short way.  So let's rework the code to address this issue:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

N = 7

def drawStar(turtle, sides, size):

    """ Get turtle turtle to draw a star of sides sides of size size """

    turtle.right(18)

    for _ in range(sides - 1):
        turtle.forward(size)
        turtle.right(6 * 180 / sides)

    turtle.forward(size)

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor("lightgreen")

alex = Turtle()
# alex.speed("fastest")
alex.color("hotpink")

for i in range(5):
    alex.up()    
    alex.forward(30)
    alex.down() 

    drawStar(alex, N, 30)

    alex.left(8)

alex.hideturtle()

screen.exitonclick()
```

Under normal speed, and only 5 iterations instead of 15, this optimization of turns knocks 1/3 off the time it takes to draw the stars!  Yet produces the same result:

[image]